# Review form to appear after On-click on a button

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1

On the product page, I want to create a button on the product page which will trigger review form to appear. Currently, I am having just form on the page. And submit button of this form. So where to change it?

**EDIT**  till now I have disappeared the form from the page using this in custom.less file.

```
form#review-form {
    display: none;
}
```

So now I want to create a button and give it a javascript like `onClick` to display block

Comment: Is this in a tab or just a standard div? would you have a link so an example can be provided

Comment: Firstly it was in a tab now I separated. its occurring after add to cart div. @DavaGordon

Comment: I seperated it using <move element="reviews.tab" destination="main.content" after="-"/>   @DavaGordon

Comment: do you want same functionality like on this website https://www.smartparcelbox.com/smart-parcel-delivery-box-medium-dark-grey.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a simple toggle of the reviews for the review just do somethink like

```
<a class="review-link">Write Review</a>
<script>
jQuery('.review-link').on('click', function() {
       jQuery('form#review-form').slideToggle('slow');
}
</script>
```

Depending on your version of jquery It could be $ or if you have defined another variable via noConflict()

Sorry but best I can do from my phone

Comment: Do you have any idea where I have to put this code ?

Comment: to edit the form its in your theme directory under review/form.phtml

this link can be added to catalog/product/view.phtml
<a class="review-link"><?php echo $this->__('Add Your Review') ?></a>

Without viewing the site i could not be more specific sorry

Comment: hi I got solved by doing something like this    require(['jquery'],function($){
jQuery('#review_id').on('click', function() {


if(!jQuery('form#review-form').is(':visible'))

{
     alert('inshowphase');
        jQuery('form#review-form').show();
    }
else{
    alert('hidedone');
jQuery('form#review-form').hide();

}

Comment: and file was  product/view/details.phtml