# Jump to review-form tab from magento product view

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, review, tabs

In my magento 1.9.0.1 store I correctly have the review-form in tab, on product page. If i click on "review link" in rating box I go to product review page. I want go to review-form tab on same page and not to the product review page. How I can do this? Is there some JS or code for doing this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are two ways to approach this, both described on SE/SO already: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193272/review-form-to-appear-after-on-click-on-a-button?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441867/magento-link-to-review-form-of-bought-product-for-email

Comment: Thanks, but it work only if the review are not in tab. If i open the review tab and click on the link write"review" all work and like an anchor the page jump correctly. But if the rewiew tab is not clicked nothing happened. I dont'know if can write my website here

Comment: If it is not a problem for you or your client(s) nobody else here will mind if you provide the URL ;) In fact, to be honest, I did not really get your description, so maybe this will be helpful (else some screens may work as well, to get a better idea).

Comment: you have right, here is some screen more explicative: https://ibb.co/kSi4Fc   https://ibb.co/g7v6Tx